# No Network/Super admin after enabling Network

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I've just successfully enabled networks in WP 3.2.1.

However, at top right, I have **no Network Admin** under my (admin) username.

If I go to /wp-admin/network, I receive "**You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page**."

- In my WP_Sitemeta table, **site_admins** is set to `a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;s:3:"My_Username";}`.
- **admin_user_id** in this table is blank.
- In, WP_Usermeta, **SL_capabilities** is set to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` for my admin username.

I had disabled all plugins before install.

**wp-config** contains the following:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true );
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.superlogical.net' );
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

**Update**: I had another look at wp-config.php, and the entries above were not there. I don't know why.

Adding them added "My Sites" to the top left under Dashboard.

However, I have no ability to add a site, and I get the same error when visiting /wp-admin/network.

Comment: Have you logged out and logged back in?

Comment: @Brian Fegter: Yes mate.  No change.  See below for solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed Wordpress 3.2.1 fresh on a new domain, and then enabled Multi-Site, which functioned as documented.  I could reach /wp-admin/network without problems.

Comparing the database of this WP with the problem installation, in the **wp_sitemeta** table, **admin_email was not set** for the problem site.

Also, **wp_sitemeta > site_admins** was different.  The problem website had it set to:

```
a:1:{i:0;N;i:1;s:3:"username";}
```

The correct value was:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"username";}
```

Setting admin_email to my Admin account's email and changing siteadmins to the correct value above added "Site Admin" to the top right drop down box under my username.

However, when trying to load the Site Admin section, my browser produced an error:

> **This webpage has a redirect loop**. The webpage at
>   [baseurl]/wp-signup.php?new=[baseurl] has resulted in too many
>   redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party
>   cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server
>   configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

After I **added www.** to:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com' );
```

in wp-config.php, I was able to load /wp-admin/network without problem, and all network / multi-site options were visible.

Comment: Note that the redirect loop was probably being created by an .htaccess directive.  I did not have this problem. Also for the `site_admins` value, use an online serializer/unserializer to modify the value and paste it back in to the DB.

Comment: Any chance of writing a SQL to do this edit in the database?
I tried this: insert into wp_sitemeta (site_id, meta_key, meta_value) values(1, 'site_admins', 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"lucre";'}); but it gives me an error about mariabdb

Answer (score 0):

the new username has to be SERIALISED. use this: http://serialize.onlinephpfunctions.com/

type:

```
array("0" => "siteadminusernamehere");
```

where 0 = your user number
and the other stuff is your site admin username.